Automatically update newer data, while keeping older data in report
So what I'm trying to do is to keep automatically updating the Power BI report, but only for data not older than one month, while keeping the older data in report as well, just not updating it.
This is quite a specific request and there's reason for that - I have database, that is only one year old, but it already has 5 mil records. Obviously it won't be possible to auto-update it every morning, since the select alone will take more than 10 minutes (if server survives that operation), so I figured I need a way to keep older information intact, while only auto-updating newer information. But I don't know a way to do that. I tried to make task easier, but got confirmation that all data needs to be in that report.
I was thinking about having two separate queries with older and newer info and it might work, but the older one will still need to auto-update every month. Maybe there's a way to aggregate this data, so only new one will need to update?
Does anyone know of a way achieving that?

You need to use incremental refresh, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/incremental-refresh-configure. this will allow you to add in or update rows to the existing dataset
